# MySQL limit a time range by a interval of 10

Tags: php, mysql, raspberry-pi, intervals

I am trying to create a array of temperture readings within a time range, but limit it to only 1 reading for every 10 readings. Can one help me to add this function to the code below? :)

```
$dataArray=array();

$sql="SELECT * FROM $sensorID WHERE Time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL $timeDuration HOUR) AND Time <= NOW()";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

if ($result) {
    while (
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $time=$row["Time"];
    $temperature=$row["Temp"];
    $dataArray[$time]=$temperature;
  }}
```

Cheers

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please stop using PHP's deprecated mysql API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show every 10th row?

```
$i=0;
if ($result) {
    while (
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if($i % 10 == 0)
    {
        $time=$row["Time"];
        $temperature=$row["Temp"];
        $dataArray[$time]=$temperature;
    }
    $i++;
  }}
```

Comment: Yes i need to get every 10th row, i have tried your code, but it doesn't work for me :-/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Michael O.

Its working for me now :D

```
$i=0;
if ($result) {
while (
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
if($i % 10 == 0)
{
$time=$row["Time"];
$temperature=$row["Temp"];
$dataArray[$time]=$temperature;
}
$i++;
}}
```